Using "poise" as standalone verb
English as second language person trying to increase vocabulary and learning to to write.
Can I use the word "poise" as verb like I used in following statement? While Dictionary defines it as both verb and noun. Write for me bot in ChatGPT says that the word "poise" is mostly used as noun and suggested couple of alternative statements.
Original Sentence

Despite unable to control her giggles, she poised lemon held in her spoon while jogging the track.

ChatGPT Response
"Poise" is typically used as a noun meaning graceful and elegant bearing in a person, or as a verb meaning to hold something in a balanced or steady position. So, while it can mean balancing or holding steady, it’s generally not used as a standalone verb like "poised the lemon".
In this context, "balanced" or "steadied" would be clearer and more correct. Here’s a refined version:

Despite being unable to control her giggles, she balanced the lemon on her spoon as she jogged around the track.

Or, if you want to keep "poise" in the sentence:

Despite her giggles, she kept her poise, balancing the lemon on her spoon as she jogged around the track.

This retains the intended meaning and uses "poise" in a more conventional way.

This question is better suited to our sister SE site English Language Learners.

To use poise as a verb, it is typically used as "[something] poised [something].

[Mark] poised [himself] on the forward edge of the diving platform, his back to the water and just the balls of his feet and toes on the edge, to perform a one and a half revolution back flip with a twist.

The answer to your question is "No."
"she poised lemon held in her spoon" sounds completely alien to a native speaker of English (me).
If you want to use "poised" as a verb, the proper construction would be for example,

she stood ready, the [lemon] poised [in her spoon].

Also "Despite unable to control her giggles" sounds wrong, the proper construction in English is "Despite being unable to control her giggles".
So in full,

Despite being unable to control her giggles, she held the lemon poised in her spoon while jogging the track.


I would further add that "poised in her spoon" sounds odd. If the lemon fits in her spoon (ladle??), then it doesn't need to be balanced. Instead, I suggest "poised on her spoon."

@Rob Fair enough; I agree.
